# Low quality legend symbols in QGIS

Tags: qgis, legend

The legend symbols in my QGIS map composition render very pixelated, like this:

[image]

However, they render fine for actual point data. They appear this way within map composer, when printing, and when exporting to PDF. The symbols are all "Simple marker" types. Is there a setting somewhere to fix this? Been using QGIS for a few years now and can't recall ever having this issue. I'm presenting using QGIS v2.2.0 on Mac OS X 10.9.3

Comment: Have you tried to use 300 dpi as export resolution under the composition tab of the print composer?

Comment: Issue seems to be fixed after updating to QGIS v2.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the symbols look bad in the print composer preview, but they are rendered fine when saving to PNG. (Using 2.4 on Win8)

[image]